# Is there an infinite hierarchy of sequences whose reciprocals diverge, starting with the natural numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series, harmonic-numbers

It is well known that the sum of the reciprocals of the function $f_0(n)=n$  (the harmonic series) diverges:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\,\frac{1}{n}=\infty$$

Similarly, the sum of the reciprocals of the prime numbers $f_1(n)=p_n$ diverges.

We also know that, since $p_n \sim n \ln n$,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{f_0(n)}{f_1(n)} = 0$$

> Is there an infinite hierarchy of sequences $f_k:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$
>
> 1. $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\,\frac{1}{f_k(n)}$ diverges
> 2. $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{f_k(n)}{f_{k+1}(n)} = 0$?

Comment: You can read more about the distinction between small and large sets [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_set_(combinatorics)). Specifically, the still unproven conjecture by Erdős might be relevant to your question.

Comment: I don't exactly see how the Erdős–Turán conjecture relates to this question, since condition 2 in my question has nothing to do with arithmetic progressions AFAICS.

Comment: You are probably right, I just threw it out here without putting much thought into it. OTOH, _you_ seem to have thought about it a lot. :)

Comment: I'm thinking that maybe something like $f_k(n)=n(\ln n)^k$ might work, but I'm not sure whether this diverges for all $k$.

Comment: Of course $\sum1/(n(\log n)^a)$ diverges for every $a$. This is one of the most discussed series, just after the Riemann series $\sum1/n^a$, and it even has a name: http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/series/bertrand/bertrand.html